# BizTalk Mapping:Source record does not exists but need to map and pass default value

Tags: xslt, biztalk

I have a source schema in which a particular record is optional and in the source message instance the record does not exist. I need to map this record to destination record, scenario goes like if the source record doesn't exist, need to map a default value 0 to destination nodes. and If it does exists , need to pass the source node values as it is (followed by few arithmetic operations).

I have tried using various combinations of functoids like logical existence followed by value mapping,record count ,string existence,etc. Also tried using c# within scripting functoid and also xslt , nothing works.its very tough to deal with mapping non existing records. I have several records on top of this record which are mapped just fine and they do exists. having trouble only with this one.No matter how many combination of c# and xslt code i write , it feels like scripting functoid will never accept a non existence record or node link. Mind you that this record if exists ,can repeat multiple times.

Using BizTalk2013r2.

Answer (score 2):

If the record doesn't exist (record is not coming, not even as **< record/>**) you can use this simple combination of Functoids.

[image]

Link the record to Logical Existence, if exist it will be sent by the top Value Mapping. If doesn't exit the second condition will be true and the zero will be sent from the value mapping in the bottom.

Comment: This works only if the source record exists. Its not producing default value 0 or even an empty destination record if the source record is missing.

Comment: This sends a 0 if the source record doesn't exists. If you share your map and your input XML, I could help you more.